# Genesis: Add nav into custom header function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook, genesis

I am trying to make a custom header function in a Genesis child theme that includes site title, description, nav, and one additional div. The nav does not show up with this code:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_new_header' );
function genesis_do_new_header() {
    echo '<div id="title-area">';
    do_action( 'genesis_site_title' );
    do_action( 'genesis_site_description' );
    echo '</div>';
    do_action( 'genesis_do_nav' );
    echo '<div id="additional"></div>';
}
```

I then tried adding

```
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
```

after removing the after_header do_nav action with a variety of different priorities, but could not get it to go in between the site description and the #additional div. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I separated out the custom header functions and removed/added the nav in between them:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_new_header_1', 5 );
function genesis_do_new_header_1() {
    echo '<div id="title-area">';
    do_action( 'genesis_site_title' );
    do_action( 'genesis_site_description' );
    echo '</div>';
}
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_nav', 6 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_new_header_2', 7 );
function genesis_do_new_header_2() {
    echo '<div id="additional"></div>';
}
```

This works just fine for now-- but if there is a cleaner solution out there would be happy to hear it!